# Pandas: Mapping values between 2 dataframes by matching 2 columns values (composite key) to 1 column and the column labels/index of another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Question sounds to have been asked before, but couldn't apply or understand solutions for my case, hence asking...
I have a dataframe `Main` that looks like this with two columns `topic, cat` with new needed column `Value` that I want:

```
topic    |   cat   | Value(needed col)
---------------------------------
top1     | cat1    |   0
---------------------------------
top2     | cat3    |   4
---------------------------------
top4     | cat4    |   1
```

While the values for `Value` col from above are in another dataframe `Values_df` with some 80Rx30C in the form:

```
cat     | top1 | top2 | top3 | top4...top30
-------------------------------------------
cat1    | 0    |  1   | 2    | 2
-------------------------------------------
cat2    | 1    |  1   | 1    | 1
-------------------------------------------
cat3    | 2    |  4   | 3    | 3
-------------------------------------------
cat4    | 5    |  2   | 1    | 1
.
.
cat80   | 2    |  7   | 4    |
```

I tried of transposing the `Values_df` and left joining but couldn't figure out as I have multiple columns,
Another attempt I made is creating a dictionary within dictionary that looks like:
`{'cat1': {'top1':0, 'top2':1, 'top3':2, 'top4':2}}` 
and map it but stuck at mapping it.

Any way that will help me get the `Value` col added in `Main`?

Comment: Reshape that second dataframe to long format (maybe using melt) before joining

Comment: Reshape the mapping dataframe by the appropriate method, as shown in the guide at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-pivoting-dataframe-objects . then use [`.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for the specific column of the target dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a mapping from `Values_df` by melting `Values_df` by [`.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and then set index on columns `topic` and `cat` by [`.set_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and specify the column `value` (column `value` is generated by [`.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html))

Then, on the `Main` dataframe, get a tuple of `topic` and `cat` for each row as a composite key for matching the mapping created by [`.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), as follows:

```
mapping = Values_df.melt(id_vars='cat', var_name='topic').set_index(['topic', 'cat'])['value']

Main['Value'] = Main[['topic', 'cat']].apply(tuple, axis=1).map(mapping)
```

**Data Input**

```
Main = pd.DataFrame({'topic': ['top1', 'top2', 'top4'], 'cat': ['cat1', 'cat3', 'cat4']})

  topic   cat
0  top1  cat1
1  top2  cat3
2  top4  cat4


data = {'cat': ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4', 'cat80'],
 'top1': [0, 1, 2, 5, 2],
 'top2': [1, 1, 4, 2, 7],
 'top3': [2, 1, 3, 1, 4],
 'top4': [2, 1, 3, 1, 9]}
Values_df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

     cat  top1  top2  top3  top4
0   cat1     0     1     2     2
1   cat2     1     1     1     1
2   cat3     2     4     3     3
3   cat4     5     2     1     1
4  cat80     2     7     4     9
```

**Mapping created:**

```
print(mapping)

topic  cat  
top1   cat1     0
       cat2     1
       cat3     2
       cat4     5
       cat80    2
top2   cat1     1
       cat2     1
       cat3     4
       cat4     2
       cat80    7
top3   cat1     2
       cat2     1
       cat3     3
       cat4     1
       cat80    4
top4   cat1     2
       cat2     1
       cat3     3
       cat4     1
       cat80    9
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

**Result:**

```
print(Main)

  topic   cat  Value
0  top1  cat1      0
1  top2  cat3      4
2  top4  cat4      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following?

```
import pandas as pd

#dummy main data
main_df = pd.DataFrame({
  'topic': ['top1', 'top2', 'top4'],
  'cat': ['cat1', 'cat3', 'cat4'],
})

#dummy values data
values_df = pd.DataFrame({
  'cat': ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4', 'cat5', 'cat6'],
  'top1': [10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  'top2': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6],
  'top3': [2, 2, 1, 3, 5, 3],
  'top4': [3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 6],
  'top5': [1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7],
})
```

`melt` the `values_df`, but, before that, we need to quickly create columns header for `values_df`:

```
cols_label = ['top' + str(x) for x in range(1, 6)]
```

In your case, `range(1, 6)` should be `range(1, 31)`.

Melt the `values_df`:

```
values_df = values_df.melt(id_vars=['cat'], value_vars=cols_label)
```

This will give us the following:

[image]

Then, merge main_df and values_df:

```
merged = main_df.merge(values_df, how='left', left_on=['cat', 'topic'], right_on=['cat', 'variable']).drop('variable', axis=1)
```

And here is the final result:

[image]